# Javascript, Socket.io - alert shows up more than one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sockets, socket.io

When I click the follow button, socket.io sends some data to the server, and then the server sends back a response number. According to what the number is, js alerts a message. But if I click the button a second time, js will alert the same message twice, and if I click it again, three times and so on. If I refresh the page, it starts all over again (click it once, alert shows up once, click it twice, alert shows up twice...)

Here's the code:

```
$('.followUser').click(function(e){
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  var user= $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().next().children().children('.userName').children().first().children().attr('id');
  var thisUserId = $.cookie('thisUserID');

  if(user != thisUserId){ //if he tries to follow himself
    var object = {
      user: user,
      userId: thisUserId
    }

    socket.emit('followUser', object); //server just adds that user to the following list of the first user
    socket.on('followUserResults', function(data){
      if(data == 1){
        alert('Something went wrong! Please refresh this page and try again'); // if they changed the id on html
      } else if(data == 0){
        alert('User was added to your following list!');
      } else if(data == 2){
        alert('This user is already on your following list!');
      }
    });

  } else {
    return false;
  }
```

Can you please help me with that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am slightly unclear as to what is trying to be achieved but I've noticed an error in your code straight away.

This code should be outside of the `$('.followuser').click` function:

```
socket.on('followUserResults', function(data){
      if(data == 1){
        alert('Something went wrong! Please refresh this page and try again'); // if they changed the id on html
      } else if(data == 0){
        alert('User was added to your following list!');
      } else if(data == 2){
        alert('This user is already on your following list!');
      }
    });
```

So your code should read like:

```
$('.followUser').click(function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    var user= $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().next().children().children('.userName').children().first().children().attr('id');
    var thisUserId = $.cookie('thisUserID');

    if(user != thisUserId){ //if he tries to follow himself
        var object = {
            user: user,
            userId: thisUserId
        }

        socket.emit('followUser', object); //server just adds that user to the following list of the first user

    } else {
        return false;
}

socket.on('followUserResults', function(data){
      if(data == 1){
          alert('Something went wrong! Please refresh this page and try again'); // if they changed the id on html
      } else if(data == 0){
          alert('User was added to your following list!');
      } else if(data == 2){
          alert('This user is already on your following list!');
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try put the `socket.on(...)` outside the click callback function, if still not working properly, I would need watch the server code.